# Working with sf and alternative co-ordinate reference systems

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to plot maps with Great Circle (GC) paths using different CRS. The code below works fine for plotting a GC between Hong Kong and Chicago airports when using WGS 84 (EPGS 4326). However, when I try a difference CRS (e.g. EPGS 3035) the line does not draw. Any ideas on what I'm missing here? Looking at the plotted maps, it looks like the GC lines and points are not being transformed correctly? Note, reference image plots at bottom of this post.

```
# Load packages
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Define Co-ordinate Reference System
crs.inuse <- 4326  # WGS 84
crs.inuse <- 3035  # ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe

# Define points of interest as Chicago O'Hare Airport (ORD)
# and Hong Kong Airport (HKG)
poi.df <- data.frame('id'=c(1, 1),
                     'IATA'=c('ORD', 'HKG'),
                     'lat'=c(41.974522, 22.308889),
                     'lon'=c(-87.906596, 113.914722),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Convert coordinate data to sf object
poi.sf <- st_as_sf(poi.df, coords=c('lon', 'lat'), crs=crs.inuse)

# Convert POINT geometry to LINESTRING
poi.sf.line <- poi.sf %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(do_union=FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast('LINESTRING')

# Convert rhumb lines to great circles
poi.sf.gcline <- poi.sf.line %>% 
  st_segmentize(units::set_units(200, km))

# Tidy up great circles so that plotted lines wrap cleanly
# across the dateline
poi.sf.gcline <- st_wrap_dateline(poi.sf.gcline, options=c('WRAPDATELINE=YES', 'DATELINEOFFSET=180'))

# Load the background map
world <- ne_countries(scale='medium', returnclass='sf')

# Plot the map
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=world) +
  geom_sf(data=poi.sf, aes(geometry=geometry), size=2.5, colour='red') +
  geom_sf(data=poi.sf.gcline, aes(geometry=geometry), size=0.5, colour='red') +
  coord_sf(crs=st_crs(crs.inuse))
```

**Drawn using EPGS 4326**
[image]
**Drawn using EPGS 3035**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix, make sure your crs.inuse is this for all of your code:

```
crs.inuse <- 4326
```

When your are plotting using ggplot, manually provide the crs in the coord_sf argument:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=world) +
  geom_sf(data=poi.sf, aes(geometry=geometry), size=2.5, colour='red') +
  geom_sf(data=poi.sf.gcline, aes(geometry=geometry), size=0.5, colour='red') +
  coord_sf(crs=st_crs(3035))
```

Here is what you get:

[image]

Comment: ok, so use WGS 84 for all calculations etc., and then only use a different crs for the actual plotting/drawing of the map?

Comment: Yes, its best to work with the same CRS for all your calculations and then switch if you need to at the end. Mixing CRS does not go well. 

Btw, did my solution work out ok for you?